# Design process for custom hardware

Tags: linux, hardware, embedded

We have a design for a custom board with multiple codecs that will be used with a iMX8 module. We haven't made a prototype yet. Hardware designer wants to test his assumptions to verify the SAI ports can be set up as desired - TDM slots, clock sources, voltage levels, etc.

As I understand it, this would be accomplished by a device tree that describes the new hardware interface. A new version of Linux would be created, and the hardware configuration could be tested, to a certain extent, before the custom board is built.

Would it be possible to configure the system like this without having the custom hardware?

It seems like the device driver is being written without having the hardware.

Comment: Do you have a development board with some ready-to-use BSP for testing? Then simply add your drivers, adapt the device tree and do some handwiring to connect your codecs to verify that the custom board will work.

Comment: @Philippos Ok, thanks. This seems to confirm my thoughts that a custom device driver needs to be written, and it makes sense to prototype with the additional codec hardware to verify the design.